# Triangular inequality, specific problem

Tags: inequality

so I stumbled onto this problem:
Consider $|6x^2 - 2|$, while $|x| \le 1$,
then $|6x^2 - 2| \le 6x^2 + 2 \le 8$, here by the triangular inequality.

My question is that while I understand why the triangular inequality holds in general, in this case, it doesn't really make any sense to me, since there is no $x$ element $[0,1)$, such that $|6x^2 - 2| = 8$. It seems like using the triangular inequality in this example (while it is correct to do so) breaks a basic rule of math.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: The statement “all human beings have a height $\le 100$ feet” is correct, even if there is no human being having that height.

Comment: The triangle inequality is $|a+b| \le |a|+|b|$. Now let $a=6x^2, b=-2$

Comment: @MartinR Maybe I should have specified my problem a bit more. So the task at hand was about Taylor expansion. We were asked to determine in what interval the (Lagrange) error is < 1/100. We then determined the Lagrange error to be as follows: (6*h^2 - 2)/(6(1+h^2)^3). Obviously the task means that the absolute value of said error must be < 1/100; so we estimated both the denomiator and the numberator. The numerator is where my problem is. So if what you say is right, then that would mean that if we estimate the numerator to be <= 8, we might not get the optimal interval that is required.

Comment: @Vasya Yes, I understood that already, sorry for being unclear about that in my question.

Comment: @Glace: you should've explained the context as you did in your comments. In this case, it's not necessary to use the triangle inequality. $|6x^2-2| \le 4$ if $|x| \le 1$

Comment: Thank you, after thinking about it again myself, I think I finally wrapped my mind around it (not that there was much to be wrapped around to begin with). Thank you man :)